# Left and right Weyl representations are inequivalent representations

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry

We introduce the two-component spinors in the following representations:

$$
\psi_\alpha \rightarrow\psi'_\alpha=\mathcal{M}_\alpha^\beta\psi_\beta$$
$$
\bar\psi_\dot{\alpha}\rightarrow\bar\psi_\dot{\alpha}'=\mathcal{M^*}_\dot{\alpha}^\dot{\beta}\bar{\psi}_\dot{\beta}
$$
Where the matrix $\mathcal{M}\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$

These two representations are not equivalent because there is no matrix for which $\mathcal{M^*}=\mathcal{CMC^{-1}}$. I don't quite see how that is true. Since the entries in $\mathcal{M^*}$ are just the complex conjugates of $\mathcal{M}$, isn't it trivial to find a matrix $\mathcal{C}$ that satisfies that condition?

In other words, how can we prove that there is no such matrix $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is 'trivial'?

Comment: Since we can choose the entries of $\mathcal{C}$ I don't see how the equation cannot be satisfied. I am basically searching for a proof of this.

Comment: The problem is to find a fixed $\mathcal{C}$ which works for all $\mathcal{M}$'s, and that's impossible as already explained by ACuriousMind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the claim that left-handed Weyl spinors and right-handed Weyl spinors are not the same.

1. An abstract way to see that there cannot be such a matrix is to first show that the two representations correspond to $(1/2,0)$ and $(0,1/2)$ in the usual parlance of expressing representations of the complexification $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})_\mathbb{C}\cong \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})\oplus\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ by representations of $\mathfrak{su}(2)\oplus\mathfrak{su}(2)$, classified by pairs of half-integers $(j_1,j_2)$. Since the $j_i$ are values of Casimirs but an equivalence of representations must preserve Casimirs, the two representations cannot be equivalent.
2. (This is cribbed from a deleted answer by [Chiral Anomaly](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/206691/chiral-anomaly) [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/443120/50583)) A concrete way to see this as follows:
   $$ M^\ast = CMC^{-1}$$
   implies that $\mathrm{tr}(M^\ast) = \mathrm{tr}(M)^\ast = \mathrm{tr}(M)$ by cyclicity of the trace, and so $\mathrm{tr}(M)\in\mathbb{R}$. But $M=\mathrm{diag}(z,z^{-1})\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ for arbitrary $z\in\mathbb{C}$, and $z + z^{-1}$ is clearly not real for such arbitrary $z$.